# Tips for mapping data structure String[ ] [ ] into model class

Tags: dozer

i need your help and tips for mapping data with dozer.

Following situation is existent:

- getting String [ ] [ ] from a service layer.

  - first [ ] represents rows
  - second [ ] represents columns

fyi : This data depends on request parameter "table".

```
// exemplary service call
String[] [] result = service.getData (String table);
String[] [] result = service.getData (Enum table);
```

Depending on parameter table, another destination entity has to be used.

example :

- String[][] for parameter "table_a" should use destination object "com.foo.TableA"
- String[][] for parameter "table_b" should use destination object "com.bar.TableB"

The Service layer can not be changed. The layer always returns this data struture as result.

My problem is that i have no good starting point for this situation.

I have to iterate over the first [] and then depends on parameter table , a mapping has to be done.

```
// useful way?
List<com.foo.TableA> mappedResult = new ArrayList<com.foo.TableA>();
for (int i = 0; i < result.size ; i++) {
    String[] rowData = result[i];
    mappedResult.add(mapper.map(rowData; com.foo.TableA.class));
}


// mapping.xml
<mappings>
  <mapping>
      <class-a>how to configure String[] ?  </class-a>
      <class-b> com.foo.TableA </class-b>

      <field>
          <a>src[0] </a>  // 1st column
          <b>column_id</b>
      </field>
  <mapping>
</mappings>
```

Any hints are welcome!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For accessing data from the String-array, i have used a wrapper

```
public class RowDataWrapper {

    private final row[];
    public RowDataWrapper (String[] row) {
        this.row=row;
    }

}
```

and its usage within mapping.xml

```
<mappings>
  <mapping>
      <class-a>foo.bar.RowDataWrapper</class-a>
      <class-b>com.foo.TableA</class-b>

      <field>
          <a>row[0] </a>  // 1st column
          <b>column_id</b>
      </field>
  <mapping>
</mappings>
```